# Random newline in powershell script

Tags: powershell, scripting

Here is a script I have that is finding the name and password of a wifi network when shows it on the screen:

```
$CmdL = @("Command1", "Command2", "WIFI NAME")
Trap  [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException] {
    Write-Color "No such WiFi exists" -Color "Red"
    Continue
}
$S = $Null
$E = Get-AllWifiPasswords
Write-Host
$S = ($E | sls ($CmdL[2])).ToString().Trim()
Write-Color $S -Color "Green"
Write-Host
```

However, if it can't find the name of the network then it adds a trailing newline to the end:

```
(newline)
No such WiFi exists
(newline)
(newline)
```

I have no idea why that newline is there, as it should not be. How can I remove it so that the error output is as follows:

```
(newline)
No such WiFi exists
(newline)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra newline comes from the fact that `Write-Color $S -Color "Green"` *also* executes when an error occurred, in which case `$S` has no value, resulting in an empty line.

While [`trap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Trap) is still supported, the [`try` / `catch` / `finally`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) statement that was introduced later offers more flexibility and clarity of control flow:

```
$CmdL = "Command1", "Command2", "WIFI NAME"
$S = $Null
$E = Get-AllWifiPasswords
Write-Host
try {
  # If the next statement causes a terminating error, 
  # which happens if the `sls` (`Select-String`) call has no output,
  # control is transferred to the `catch` block.
  $S = ($E | sls ($CmdL[2])).ToString().Trim()
  Write-Color $S -Color "Green"
}
catch {
  Write-Color "No such WiFi exists" -Color "Red"
}
Write-Host
```